# how to create RPM pkg (packaging files)

Tags: linux

I create some scripts under my Linux machine RedHat-Linux-OS-5.3

the following scripts home directory is /root/Auto_Builder

And the scripts are:

```
/root/Auto_Builder/Build_EMC.sh
/root/Auto_Builder/set_auto.pl
/root/Auto_Builder/run_all.sh
```

And some lib files are under /lib as the following

```
/lib/libssl.so.6.hmac
/lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.8e.hmac
/lib/libcrypto.so.6.hmac
/lib/libssl.so.0.9.8e.hmac
```

my question I want to create RPM that include my scripts and my lib files !

For example

After  I performed (rpm installation) :

```
rpm -i MY_FIRST_RPM.rpm
```

All scripts will be created under /root/Auto_Builder     directory (include directory creation)

And all  my lib files will created under /lib    directory

Please advice how to create this RPM hopefully it will be step by step (because I read some documents regarding RPM Build package, and it’s hard to understand them -

Comment: @jon SO is better at asking precise questions than asking for step-by-step tutorials, so you'll  have better help here if you reformulate and tell us what you don't understand in the docs you read

Comment: @Charles it's better if someone with experience write a simple and clearly steps according to my question , is the same effort  and will be help to anyone that want to Build RPM

Comment: @jon Of course it's better for you but here people are more inclined  to answer precise questions

Comment: It's not really a good idea to install into specific user's home directory, especially root. Also, those libraries belong to other packages so you should just define a dependency on those packages, not inlcude them.

Comment: Also, you should probably read [Maximum RPM](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/), as it's the definitive guide.

Comment: I read the MAX RPM I have some remarks, I try the rpm -ba cdplayer-1.0.spec in my machine , but: I get rpm -ba : unknown option